# Conflicto en git merge sin lineas iguales modificadas

Tags: git, git-merge, conflictos

Apenas estoy entrando al mundo de git y entre mis prácticas e realizado merge a master entre distintas ramas, a lo que entiendo es que git no puede fusionar automáticamente cambios entre ramas cuando ambas ramas tienen cambios en una misma línea del archivo y es lógico, pero he notado algo curioso y es que realicé una práctica algo como esta:

Cree las ramas hotfix y test a partir de la rama master.

En master tengo un archivo html, dejo parte del código de ejemplo:

```
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos de git merge</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos git stash</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Documentación oficial</a></p>
```

En la rama hotfix realizo un cambio y lo fusiono con master, ahora el master queda de la siguiente manera.

```
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos de git merge</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos git stash</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Documentación oficial de git</a></p>
```

Siendo la última linea que se modificó.

Ahora realizo un cambio en la rama test quedando de esta manera:

```
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos de git merge</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos git stash</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Documentación oficial</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Video tutoriales</a></p>
```

y al querer fusionar con el master me salta el error de conflicto de AUTO-mergin.

Ahí en estos caso no se debería de hacer un auto-mergin de manera recursiva?

Algo más curioso es que he notado que si realizo un cambio antes o después de la linea modifica en la rama hostfix, al realizar el merge, es cuando me marca el conflicto, pero si realizo un cambio en otra sección del código por ejemplo en el primer enlace quedando así:

```
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos de git merge (Nuevos ejemplos)</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Ejemplos git stash</a></p>
    <p><a href="#">Documentación oficial</a></p>
```

De esta manera al hacer merge con la rama master si me realiza el auto-mergin de manera recursiva.

Espero me puedan ayudar a comprender el porqué de estos detalles, ya que por lo que veo entonces, git muestra este tipo de conflictos no sólo cuando el archivo sufre cambios en la misma línea, si no también al rededor de ella.

saludos y gracias,

Answer (score 1):

La forma en la que git trabaja es comparando los cambios que ambas ramas que estás tratando de mezclar introducen desde el punto en el que se bifurcaron (es más complejo que esto, pero es una forma sencilla de explicarlo). En la rama test agregaste una línea, pero la línea *anterior* a la línea que agregaste ha cambiado *en la otra rama* desde que las ramas bifurcaron. Ya que git lo que busca son líneas *comunes* entre los **3 puntos** para saber qué introdujo cada rama.... por el cambio que introdujo la otra rama sobre la línea anterior, pues asa línea no se puede considerar parte del común. Por lo tanto se tiene que presentar un conflicto ya que las 2 ramas presentan un cambio diferente sobre esa sección del mismo código.

Comment: Muchas gracias, creo le he entendido.